# Laravel Exception

Tags: laravel, exception, controller, try-catch

I want to create Customs Exceptions, and I want to catch and manage them in the controller. But I can't do it.

For example

```
use Exception;

class MyException extends Exception
{

}
```

in the controller

```
public function myFuncion($request){

        try{
           exceptFunction();
        } catch(MyException $e){
            repairIt();
        }
}

private function exceptFunction(){
     throw new MyException('f*ck');
}
```

The problem here is the code in catch is never executed! Always Laravel send me to the handler! I want to catch and manage the exception by my way in the controller!

I hope you can help (and teach) me.

Thanks

Nicolas

```
class CajaMovimientoController {

 public function anular(AnularCajaMovimientoRequest $request) {
   ...
 if ($movimiento->isIngreso()) {
            try {
                $this->checkSaldo($movimiento->apertura_id, $movimiento->valores, false);
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                dd("catch");
                return redirect()->back()->with('mensajes', $e->getMessage());
            }
            dd("anular ingreso");
        } else {
            $this->checkSaldo($movimiento->apertura_id, $movimiento->valores, true);
            dd("anular egreso");
        }
    }

    private function checkSaldo($sessionId, $valores, $ingreso) {
        $cajaApertura = CajaApertura::find($sessionId);
        $sft = 0;
        $sch = 0;
        $monto = 0;
        foreach ($valores as $valor) {
            $monto = $monto + floatval($valor->monto);
            if ($valor->cheque_id != null) {
                $sch = $sch + floatval($valor->monto);
            } else {
                $sft = $sft + floatval($valor->monto);
            }
        }
        if (!$ingreso) {
            if ($sft > $cajaApertura->efectivo) {
                throw new CajaSaldoException('No puede egresar mas efectivo del que posee');
//            return redirect()->back()->with('mensajes', 'No puede egresar mas efectivo del que posee');
            }

            if ($sch > $cajaApertura->cheque) {
                throw new CajaSaldoException('No puede egresar mas cheques del que posee');
//            return redirect()->back()->with('mensajes', 'No puede egresar mas cheques del que posee');
            }
        }
        for ($i = 0; $i < count($valores); $i++) {
            //protected $fillable = ['id','movimiento_id', 'cheque_id', 'monto'
            if ($valores[$i]->cheque_id != null) {
                $cheque = Cheque::find($valores[$i]->cheque_id);
                if ($cheque->caja_id != $cajaApertura->caja_id) {
                    throw new CajaSaldoException('No puede deshacer. Cheque no está en caja');
                }
                if ($ingreso) {
                    if ($cheque->estado != 2) {
                        throw new CajaSaldoException('No puede reingresar cheque');
                    }
                } else {
                    if ($cheque->estado != 1) {
                        throw new CajaSaldoException('No puede egresar cheque');
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

My Exception Class

```
namespace Prestamos\Exceptions;

use Exception;

class CajaSaldoException extends Exception
{
    //
}
```

Comment: There's no need for that kind of language. Could you `dd($e)` inside your catch block and see if you get the right exception? Also to throw the exception you can't do `exceptFunction();`, it has to be `$this->exceptFunction();`

Comment: Ok... I'm sorry about that. It is not problem with the kind of the Exception. it doesn't matter if I catch MyException or only Exception. It always send me to the Handler. 
If I put this into the Handler it works... but in the handler... I want to catch the Exception in the Controller.
if ($exception instanceof MyException) {
            dd('I catch you'); 
        }

Comment: What happens if you `dd($e);` inside the catch block? Are you able to see the exception being thrown?

Comment: Nothing happen!  It sends me to handler and I can see the error in the browser (I'm not handle it in the Hanlder) 
Whoops, looks like something went wrong.
(1/1) MyException
Here the message
And the trace!

Comment: Can we see the full controller please? I gave it a try and everything is working as expected. Quite odd that you are not able to handle it there.

Comment: I've edited the post with a fragment of my really code... There are 2 methods involved in the request's process...

Comment: What happens if you change `} catch (Exception $e) {` to `} catch (\Exception $e) {` ?

Comment: It works!!! but... Why does it happen? and How can I catch only "MyException"?

Comment: Wrote a detailed answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you want to catch an exception, make sure you are referencing the correct exception in the catch block.

So either, you would reference the FQCN of the class like this

```
try {

} catch(\App\Exceptions\CustomException $exception) {

}
```

Or, you would add your use statement at the top of your class

```
use App\Exceptions\CustomException; 

try {

} catch(CustomException $exception) {

}
```

In your particular case, what is happening is, you are trying to catch a `\App\Exceptions\CustomException` without adding the use statements.

```
try {

} catch(CustomException $exception) {

}
```

What happens in this case is, your code block is looking to catch a `App\Http\Controllers\CajaMovimientoController\CustomException` exception.

Since it can't find it, the exception is then handled by Laravel as a general exception. Read more about [namespaces](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.php).

Comment: I Have use App\Exceptions\CajaSaldoException;
but if I put catch(CajaSaldoException $e)
it sends me to handler

Comment: Could you edit your answer with the contents of `App\Exceptions\CajaSaldoException`?

Comment: Your namespace for the exception is `Prestamos\Exceptions`, did you add `use \Prestamos\Exceptions\CajaSaldoException` at the top of your class?

Comment: Yes, I did! but if I change it use \Prestamos\Exceptions\CajaSaldoException it works. When I import the Models I don't put the first slash...

Comment: I definitely need read more about namespaces. Sorry.. I'm new in php and laravel

Comment: Yes, it was just a namespacing issue. Good luck.